# where store user login info?

Tags: asp.net

i wrote an sample and test it on my host(it is shared) .
and place a machineKey in my web config.
i create tree type of storing data :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {   
            Session["x"] = "A";
            HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("y", "B");
            Application["z"] = "C";
        }
    }
```

and put button on my form and write in its event:

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          try
          {
             Label1.Text = Session["x"].ToString();
         }
         catch (Exception err)
         {
             Label1.Text = err.Message;
         }

        try
        {
              Label2.Text = HttpContext.Current.Application["y"].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Label2.Text = err.Message;

        }

        try
        {
            Label3.Text =  Application["z"].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Label3.Text = err.Message;
        }


    }
```

when iis recycle and throw away any cache/memory contents at any time case i lost all of my data in all type.all returns Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

user come and want to log in , now how can i and where can i store id or username of correct user until when iis recycle i have my data and can realize user is logged?
is cookies have good to store this data like username and password of user?

Comment: Is cookies have good to store this data like username and password of user? > No that is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at using a more persistent place to store that information, such as SQL Server. [This Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604) explains how to configure your site to use SQL Server to store session state.

There are tons of other blog articles that explain how to do this, so you won't be left scratching your head :)

EDIT:
OK, looking at [the available session state modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it looks like you might need to look at `StateServer` mode, since that does support ASP.NET sites running in a web farm environment.

For reference, [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325056) explains how you could use SQL Server session state in a web farm.

Comment: thanks Jason but my site is on a shared web farm and i can not configure sql server settings

Answer (score 0):

If you can store files on  the server you could try a file based provider for Membership System

http://madskristensen.net/post/XML-membership-provider-for-ASPNET-20.aspx